# $ListItemCollection = @() Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline

Tags: xml, csv, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am getting the following error when I tried to run this script.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> C:\AIR\air.ps1
At C:\AIR\air.ps1:13 char:1
+ $ListItemCollection = @()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

I am trying to import data from an on premise sharepoint 2010 system. The applications that was used to build the form save some of the data in XML. I am trying to import the XML data to a CSV file.

Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -ErrorAction SilentyContinue

```
$siteurl = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:7000/accidentreports"

$listname = "Accident Incident Report"

$web = Get-SPWeb -identity $siteurl

$list = $web.Lists[$listname]|

$ListItemCollection = @()


$list.Items | foreach {

$ExportItem = New-Object PSObject

$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Id" -value $_["ID"]

$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Title" -value $_["Title"]

$ExportItem | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "FormXml" -value $_["FormXml"]

$ListItemCollection += $ExportItem

}


#Export the results Arry to CSV file

$ListItemCollection | Export-CSV "C:\AIR\AIR.csv" -NoTypeInformation

#Dispose the web object

$web.Dispose()
```

What I am expecting is to import the XML data to a CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the '|' at the end `$list = $web.Lists[$listname]|`